# Can I use Revolution Slider Revolution without Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I don't use a CMS like Wordpress to develop websites, however I'd like to use Slider Revolution.
Is there a way to do so?

Should I use wordpress to configure the slider then export the HTML/CSS/JS and include it in my project?

Comment: Did you find any good solution? I would use with React.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the footer on https://www.sliderrevolution.com/ there are several additional options there, including a jQuery version: https://www.themepunch.com/links/slider_revolution_jquery

Comment: The jQuery version was last updated 18 June 2018 so it looks like it's been discontinued.